# PHP Time going mental for one hour at midnight every day

Tags: php, time

I run this script which works sweet estimating how much time before something weather related happens. But a midnight it goes crazy and for the whole midnight hour, it returns crazy negative times like -1100 minutes and stuff, then when it gets to 0100 hrs it's back to normal and reports, like 20 mintues etc.

Script:

```
  $timenow = date("H:i:s");

  $eventtime= strtotime("$gettimefromtextfile"); //time the weather event will happen in the near future
 $TimeEnd = strtotime($timenow);
 $Difference = ($eventtime - $TimeEnd);
if ($Difference >= 0) {
 $minutes = floor(($Difference / 60)); 
// print how many minutes until an event happens, discard it if event is in the past
```

I know the date function had issues with midnight up to PHP 5.3. But I am running PHP 5.3 so shouldn't be an issue. I don't need the date, it is only time I need, weather related stuff is reported only hours difference at most.

Any suggestions on an alternative function or coding that will stop this spasm at midnight?

Comment: Did you try using `DateTime()`?

Comment: No I looked at it, but I don't quite understand the function. How could I use it to display the time now only and no date?

Comment: what does `$gettimefromtextfile"` look like?  can you give some example values?

Comment: it just pulls time from text files like which are in this format 0215, and formats it to this 02:15:00 for example. Could it be strtotime being the problem?

Comment: `PHP Time going mental for one hour at midnight every day`, to be honest, this question made me lough, so loudly, I think it get possed at midnight for one hour. +1 for this funny title, lol...

Comment: `$eventtime= strtotime("$gettimefromtextfile");` try putting in the `mental hour` instead of `$gettimefromtextfile` and see what happens.. Please try to describe what happens (timeout, errors.. etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `DateTime::diff`? Don't reinvent the wheel!

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon'); 

$next = new DateTime('18:00:01');
$now = new DateTime();
$diff = $next->diff($now);

echo $diff->format('%h hours, %i minutes');
?>
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: That looks superb, I'll amend my code today with that and wait until midnight and see if it behaves properly :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArnoldJRimmer don't forget to change the code to your timezone, or you're gonna have a bad time! And if everything works properly accept the answer!